# How to print EOL in \message?

Tags: printing

I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\message{Hello \\ world!}
\end{document}
```

However, the `\\` is not printed as an end-of-line. I'm getting this in the console:

```
Hello \\ world!
```

What's the right syntax here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version works (I am assuming that priting end-of-line means for you going to the next line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\message{Hello ^^J world!}
\end{document}
```

(`^^J` means newline character).

Comment: This works! Just curious, where did you get this information?

Comment: @yegor256 It is a standard method, described in "The TeXbook".

Comment: This `\`^^J` is the value of the `\newlinechar` parameter

Answer (score 4):

The (otherwise good) answer by [Przemysław Scherwentke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629458/4427) glosses over several details.

You cannot use `\\` to separate lines in `\message`, because `\\` is a *typesetting* instruction.

There is a general mechanism in TeX to produce new lines in `\write` or `\message` instructions, namely to use a character whose character code (the ASCII code) is the current value of the internal integer `\newlinechar`.

In the TeXbook we find (page 228)

> The ⟨token list⟩ of a `\write` ought to be rather short, since
> it makes one line of output. Some implementations of TeX are unable to
> write long lines; if you want to write a lot of stuff, just give
> several `\write` commands. Alternatively, you can set TeX's `\newlinechar`
> parameter to the ASCII code number of some character that you want to
> stand for ”begin a new line”; then TeX will begin a new line whenever it
> would ordinarily output that character to a file.
> For example, one way to output two lines to the terminal
> in a single `\write` command is to say
>
> ```
> \newlinechar=`\^^J
> \immediate\write16{Two^^Jlines.}
> ```

It should be noted that plain TeX doesn't set a value for `\newlinechar`, so it keeps the default value −1.

To the contrary, LaTeX has always set `` \newlinechar=`\^^J ``, so you can always do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\message{Hello^^Jworld!}
\end{document}
```

Note that spaces around `^^J` are preserved in the `\message`. This produces new lines in `\message`, `\write` and `\typeout` instructions.

Comment: +1 from me.  The result of `\message` also depends on the encoding of the shell and on character-translation/tcx. E.g., ```\newlinechar=-1 \catcode`\^^M=12 \catcode`\^^J=12 \message{Hello^^J^^Mworld!}\csname stop\endcsname\bye```: pdftex: L1: "Hello", L2: "^^Mworld!" / xetex:  "Hello^^J^^Mworld!" / luatex: L1: "Hello", L2: "world!" . The impact of char-translation can be seen with luatex when omitting `^^J`(=line feed) where carriage return(input as ^^M) is not translated in terminal-output and thus executed by the shell which displays the message and does carriage-return but no linefeed.